# How to inherit from std::runtime_error?

Tags: c++, inheritance, runtime-error

For example:

```
#include <stdexcept>
class A { };
class err : public A, public std::runtime_error("") { };
int main() {
   err x;
   return 0;
}
```

With `("")` after `runtime_error` I get:

```
error: expected '{' before '(' token
error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
error: expected ')' before string constant
```

**else (without `("")`) I get**

```
In constructor 'err::err()':
error: no matching function for call to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error()'
```

What's going wrong?

(You can test it here: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
class err : public A, public std::runtime_error
```

And not:

```
class err : public A, public std::runtime_error("")
```

As you are doing above. If you want to pass an empty string to the constructor of `std::runtime_error`, do it this way:

```
class err : public A, public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    err() : std::runtime_error("") { }
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Here is a [live example](http://ideone.com/d7WtzK) to show the code compiling.

Comment: I tried it on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php, and your suggestion gives me `no matching function for call to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error()'`

Comment: @MiloChen: Are you sure you copied everything correctly? I added a link to a live example that shows the code compiles correctly

Comment: Oh, I see, it won't compile if I miss out the constructor `err() : std::runtime_error("") { }`. It's not that I *want* to pass an empty string - I'm *forced* to.

Comment: @MiloChen: If this answer solves the problem in your question, please consider marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 5):

Would just like to add that alternatively the `err` class could take a string message and simply forward it to `std::runtime_error`, or an empty string by default, like so:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>

class err : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    err(const std::string& what = "") : std::runtime_error(what) {}
};
```

Comment: you might want to simplify further and inherit std::runtime_error constructor with: `using std::runtime_error::runtime_error`;